# In Newtheoremstyle, why can't I leave entries blank?

Tags: formatting, theorems

The following code is throwing an error of "missing number, treated as zero". But it says [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems#Custom_styles) that any parameters in theorem style I leave blank will be treated as default. What is going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\newtheoremstyle{MyTheorem}% name of the style to be used
  {}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {}% measure of space to indent
  {}% name of head font
  {}% punctuation between head and body
  {}% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {}% Manually specify head


\theoremstyle{MyTheorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Any $\ell \in L$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial $p \in F[x]$ which splits in $L$ into distinct linear factors.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ** {}% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space** so you need to make it `{ }` :-)

Comment: @touhami I notice if I leave the font names blank, it doesn't go to the defaults (`mathbf`), it goes to `normalfont`. That's funny.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default fonts are not set, except maybe by some classes. So if you leave one blank, no font command is issued (except for a `\normalfont` used to reset the font parameters). `\bfseries` (not `\mathbf`) is used by the plain theorem style, but it is not a default.

Comment: @EricAuld `\normalfont` is (by definition) the default font isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `amsthm` is amsthdoc.pdf (`texdoc amsthm`) which describes this command on page 9.

The arguments that have special meaning for empty are noted with footnotes and this does not include the last but one argument for space after the theorem head, so leaving that empty is like `\hspace{}` which is an error.